# Draw Lines Load From Plist in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

I am Save the Draw lines x and y position to Plist from **touchesMoved event** Below Code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = YES;
    NSLog(@"You are drawing");
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint.y -= 20;


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSNumber *numx = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentPoint.x];
    NSNumber *numy = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentPoint.y];
    [xpoints insertObject:numx atIndex:[xpoints count]];
    [ypoint insertObject:numy atIndex:[ypoint count]];

    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Lines" ofType:@"plist"]; //5

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
    path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Lines.plist"];


    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    //here add elements to data file and write data to file
    int value = [xpoints count];

    [data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value] forKey:@"Array_count"];
    NSString *obj_str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",numx,numy];
    NSString *key=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];
    [data setObject:obj_str forKey:key];



    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    [data release];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f%@%f", lastPoint.x, @"-",lastPoint.y];
   // NSLog(@"Hello is %i",[xpoints count]);
    lblxy.text=string;

    NSString *string2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f%@%f", currentPoint.x, @"-",currentPoint.y];
   // NSLog(@"Hello is %i",[xpoints count]);
    lbllast.text=string2;


    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    mouseMoved++;

    if (mouseMoved == 10) {
        mouseMoved = 0;
    }

}
```

This code Saves x and y points to plist like first point save to key 0 and value x ,y points like 0-25,54 and 1-56,98 .....etc.

Save code is Working Perfectly...!,My load x and y points from plist Below Code:

```
    - (IBAction)btn_load:(id)sender {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
        path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Lines.plist"];

        drawImage.image =nil;


        NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

        //here add elements to data file and write data to file    
        int value;
        value = [[data objectForKey:@"Array_count"] intValue];

        CGFloat lastx;
        CGFloat lasty;

        for(int i=1;i<=value;i++)
        {
            NSString *key=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
            NSLog(@"This is from .plist %@", [data objectForKey:key]);

            NSString *my_points=[data objectForKey:key];
            NSArray *components = [my_points componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
            [[components objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];

            if(i==1)
            {
                lastx = [[components objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
                lasty = [[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
            }

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
            [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),lastx , lasty);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [[components objectAtIndex:0] floatValue], [[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]);
            CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            lastx = [[components objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
            lasty = [[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
        }


}
```

My output is Drawing Below:

[image]

My loading x and y points from plist output is Below:

[image]

My Problem is Loading Draw line from plist not perfectly like last x and y points problem..!

I want output Perfect for Drawing lines from x and y points..!

Please help with me any one us with greatly appreciated..!

Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving your "line breaks."  A property list can contain arrays.  Maybe you should collect each "drawing" in an array itself.  Also, you are not saving the color.  Try this...

In touchesBegin, you are starting a new "drawing" so create an array to hold all points for that "drawing."  In touchMove, add to that array.  in touchEnd, you are done with that, so you can put that drawing to the file, and start over on the next "begin touch."

The key is that you need to know when you start a new "drawing segment" so you can "move" the point and start drawing again.