# Best way to store and load Freehand Drawing Lines for every image

Tags: ios, image, plist

I found this post [Draw Lines Load From Plist in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151467/draw-lines-load-from-plist-in-iphone-sdk?rq=1) about saving and loading your Freehand Drawing from plist.

In my app I am able to draw on a captured photo and save it as a new image in my photo library. But I want to just save the photo without the drawing to my photo library and be able to load my Freehand Drawing Lines manually whenever I load the original photo.

In the above named link he saves his linecoordinates in a plist. Is it effective to create for every photo a new plist?? Any ideas? Please help :(

I would really appreciate any ideas you might have! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason he uses line coordinates is because the mobile devices receive the data the same way (relative to previous or absolute). So unless the size of the line coordinates is bigger than a compressed pixel array (png, jpg, etc), this is the best way. For simplicity though, I would just keep that format.

If size is a problem for you, just use zlib (http://www.zlib.net/) to compress/uncompress the data - it's available on all mobile devices.

You could also use different algorithms to reduce the size of the data prior to zlib compression - for instance, if all coordinates are relative to the previous one, the values would be smaller meaning you could encode it in a smaller type of data - integer to byte for instance - or a dynamic one (ie: 1 byte + 0 if done 1 if another byte) + ....).